# getting Null Values from Database to jTable

Tags: java

I have a little problem when I'm loading my database to my jTable. The String which should be blank turn into null and I just don't know how to fix this? I'm relative new and didn't work with objects and GUIs before. If you look at the picture the first 3 rows should look like number 4 (1-3 from database and 4 new added). By the comment here the rows should be changed?

[image]

```
public DefaultTableModel DatenbankLaden() {
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null) {
                        return o.getClass();

                    }

                }

                return Object.class;
            }

        };

        try {

            populate(dtm);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Laden Fehlgeschlagen");
        }
        
         for (int i = 0; i < dtm.getRowCount(); i++) {  \\here
                for (int j = 0; j < dtm.getColumnCount(); j++) { 
                    Object ob = dtm.getValueAt(i, j);
                if (ob == null || ob.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    dtm.setValueAt("na", i, j);
                }
                }
            }

        return dtm;
    }

    private TableModel populate(DefaultTableModel dtm) {

        try {

            dtm.addColumn("Auftragsnummer");
            dtm.addColumn("Auftragsdatum");
            dtm.addColumn("Auftraggeber");
            dtm.addColumn("Telefon");
            dtm.addColumn("E-mail");
            dtm.addColumn("Lieferadresse");
            dtm.addColumn("Beschreibung");
            dtm.addColumn("Fertigungszeit");
            dtm.addColumn("Fertigungsbeginn");
            dtm.addColumn("Fertiggestellt");
            dtm.addColumn("Lieferzeit");
            dtm.addColumn("Versenden");
            dtm.addColumn("Versendet");
            dtm.addColumn("Beim Kunden");
            dtm.addColumn("Auftragerledigt");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/meinedb", "root", "root123");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM ROOT.AUFTRÄGE ";
            Statement S = con.createStatement();
            rst = S.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rst.next()) {
                nummer++;
                dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                    rst.getInt(1),
                    rst.getString(2),
                    rst.getString(3),
                    rst.getString(4),
                    rst.getString(5),
                    rst.getString(6),
                    rst.getString(7),
                    rst.getInt(8),
                    rst.getString(9),
                    rst.getBoolean(10),
                    rst.getInt(11),
                    rst.getString(12),
                    rst.getBoolean(13),
                    rst.getString(14),
                    rst.getBoolean(15)

                });
                
                
                

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        
       

        return dtm;
    }
```

It would be very nice if you could answer me the question.

Comment: If you have to add artificial text to your question, it means your question doesn't contain enough information. What is supposed to happen? What do you get instead? Which empty strings in which part of your code become nulls? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Not in the comments, please. Instead, [edit] your question and add the necessary information - all of it, and remove the "filler" text.

Comment: So is this better ??